# react-js based web page crashes when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using Reactjs, redux, webpack and webpack server to develop a website.

The website crashes when I refresh a certain pages. To be more specific when I visit   http://localhost:8080/article/**Id**   the page works like a charm, but when I hit refresh the page turns to white with errors.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/article/scripts/vendor.bundle.js?cfd99d78961c5e13afca 404 (Not Found)
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/article/scripts/vendor.bundle.js?cfd99d78961c5e13afca' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

The error displayed by Chrome is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT3pp.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfqap.png).

My webpack config page looks like this :

```js
//webpack.config.js    

var webpack = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
var path = require('path')

var isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
var cssDev = ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
var cssProd = ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    use: [{
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                minimize: 'true'
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
        }
    ],
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    publicPath: '/docs'
})
var cssConfig = isProd ? cssProd : cssDev

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './src/app.js',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'docs'),
        filename: 'scripts/[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, path.resolve(__dirname, './src/lib')],
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
              },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: cssConfig
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    'file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]',
                    'image-webpack-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(xml|json|ico)$/i,
                use: [
                    'file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]',
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'docs'),
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        stats: 'errors-only',
        open: true,
        disableHostCheck: true,
        historyApiFallback: true, //when refreshing
        inline: true //reloads the entire browser page
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'styles/[name].bundle.css',
            disable: !isProd,
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'React MovieDB - Powered by The Movie Database',
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true
            },
            hash: true,
            template: './src/index.ejs'
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    watch : true
}
```

And I run the project with : `"dev": "webpack-dev-server",`

And this how my `index.ejs` looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="<%= require('./icons/apple-touch-icon.png') %>">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="<%= require('./icons/taleed.png') %>">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="<%= require('./icons/taleed.png') %>">
    <link rel="manifest" href="<%= require('./icons/manifest.json') %>">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="<%= require('./icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg') %>" color="#01d277">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/2.0.5/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <title>
        Archive Search Engine
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="smoke-screen"></div>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Honestly, I can't manage to figure out the main source of the problem because the project is based on a template and I couldn't get in touch with the template' maker.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to grab the bundle from the base path, which works just fine. But when you go to a different part of the app, you are requesting to get the bundle from `/articles/app.bundle...`. So you need to change the index file to pull from the absolute path from the server for the bundle instead of a relative path.

You need to do something like this to your `server.js` (if you use node);

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.send(template({
        css: bundle.css,
        js: bundle.js,
    }));
});
```

for example on using mustache as the template engine.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your solution

Comment: Can you post your index.html file that you serve up on the initial page load? Cause it doesn't seem like you are doing that no matter the url. The template file.

Comment: So, I tried to write something in "index.ejs" just to know if it redirect me to it. and actually when I hit refresh it redirect me to "index.ejs"

Comment: Yeah, that's where the change needs to be.

Comment: May you tell me what to change ?

Comment: I added an example of mustache of how to send back the `index.html` and render the bundle in the template. What template engine are you using?

Comment: For the index page (Where everything redirect to when things goes bananas) I am using EJS.

Comment: I believe I found a solution, thou I don't know if it is a permanent solution.
I added `publicPath: '/'` to the output of `webpack.config.js`